# How Does Alternation Differ From Boolean Or?

Tags: regex, boolean, alternation

I am trying to write a Regular Expression to read real literals based on this graph:
[image: Regex Graph]

I found that this solution works:

```
([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[Ee][\+\-]?[0-9]+)|([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
```

Notice the two parts separated via alternation:

```
([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[Ee][\+\-]?[0-9]+) 
([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
```

When I tried to switch the order of which one is on which side of the alternation symbol, it stops working

```
([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?[Ee][\+\-]?[0-9]+)
```

These parts are exactly the same as above, but now it's suddenly not working. Am I misunderstanding how the | (alternation) symbol works? Is it not the same as || (or) for boolean expressions?

Comment: It will match the first pattern it finds in the alternation. So, if you have `aab|aa` and you try it against `xxaabxx` you'd get `aab` out of it. If you flip them around, you'd receive `aa`.

Comment: @VLAZ That seems so obvious now. Thank you so much!